# JS filter through multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this `items` array and a `filterParams` array.

```js
const items = [
  {
    count: 1,
    operation: 'Change Status',
    area: 'dish_names',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  {
    count: 14,
    operation: 'Create',
    area: 'dishes',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  {
    count: 23,
    operation: 'Create',
    area: 'dish_names',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  { count: 1, operation: 'Delete', area: 'dishes', days: '2019-07-17' },
  {
    count: 2,
    operation: 'Update',
    area: 'dish_names',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  }
]

const filterParams = [
  'restaurant_menu_masters=Update',
  'dish_categories=Update',
  'dishes=Create'
]
```

What I want is to filter the `items` array using `filterParams`.

If `filterParams` array only has one element, I would easily do it like this

```
const data = items.filter(Element=> {
  let params = filterParams[0].split("=");
  return Element.area === params[0] && Element.operation === params[1]
})
```

Basically What I did was, take the params string and split it by "=" and then check first part of the param equals to `area` and the second to `operation`. My problem is it has more than one filter parameters in that array and I want to check all of that.

How do I achieve this using JS?

Any help!

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `.some` of the passed parameters, when split, match the `area` and `operation` properties:

```js
const items=[{count:1,operation:"Change Status",area:"dish_names",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:14,operation:"Create",area:"dishes",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:23,operation:"Create",area:"dish_names",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:1,operation:"Delete",area:"dishes",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:2,operation:"Update",area:"dish_names",days:"2019-07-17"}];

const fitlerParams = [
  'restaurant_menu_masters=Update',
  'dish_categories=Update',
  'dishes=Create'
]

const filtered = items.filter(
  ({ area, operation }) => fitlerParams.some((str) => {
    const [aFind, oFind] = str.split('=');
    return area === aFind && operation === oFind;
  })
);
console.log(filtered);
```

If you want to only split once for each item, you can do so in advance:

```js
const items=[{count:1,operation:"Change Status",area:"dish_names",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:14,operation:"Create",area:"dishes",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:23,operation:"Create",area:"dish_names",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:1,operation:"Delete",area:"dishes",days:"2019-07-17"},{count:2,operation:"Update",area:"dish_names",days:"2019-07-17"}];

const fitlerParams = [
  'restaurant_menu_masters=Update',
  'dish_categories=Update',
  'dishes=Create'
];
const splitParams = fitlerParams.map(str => str.split('='));

const filtered = items.filter(
  ({ area, operation }) => splitParams.some(([aFind, oFind]) => {
    return area === aFind && operation === oFind;
  })
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.some(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if that condition is `true` for any of the values in the `filterParams` array. Here is an example:

```js
const items = [{
    count: 1,
    operation: 'Change Status',
    area: 'dish_names',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  {
    count: 14,
    operation: 'Create',
    area: 'dishes',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  {
    count: 23,
    operation: 'Create',
    area: 'dish_names',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    operation: 'Delete',
    area: 'dishes',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  },
  {
    count: 2,
    operation: 'Update',
    area: 'dish_names',
    days: '2019-07-17'
  }
]

const fitlerParams = [
  'restaurant_menu_masters=Update',
  'dish_categories=Update',
  'dishes=Create'
]

const data = items.filter(Element => {
  return fitlerParams.some(value => {
    let params = value.split("=");
    return Element.area === params[0] && Element.operation === params[1]
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an array of splitted values and check if you found one true condition with `some`.

```js
const
    items = [{ count: 1, operation: 'Change Status', area: 'dish_names', days: '2019-07-17' }, { count: 14, operation: 'Create', area: 'dishes', days: '2019-07-17' }, { count: 23, operation: 'Create', area: 'dish_names', days: '2019-07-17' }, { count: 1, operation: 'Delete', area: 'dishes', days: '2019-07-17' }, { count: 2, operation: 'Update', area: 'dish_names', days: '2019-07-17' }],
    filterParams = ['restaurant_menu_masters=Update', 'dish_categories=Update', 'dishes=Create'],
    filters = filterParams.map(s => s.split('=')),
    data = items.filter(o => filters.some(([area, operation]) =>
        o.area === area && o.operation === operation));

console.log(data);
```