# Filtering an object in an array requiring 2 criteria

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What would be the best way of filtering out an object in an array based on 2 factors, I thought a simple && operator would work but I was mistaken.

```
{
  email: 'email@email.com',
  accounts: [
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Chris', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'USA' },
  ]
}
```

My original filter would just filter out based on accounts.name != 'Bob' however this can be problematic as there could be 2 Bobs with different countries.

```
let filterOut = result.accounts.filter(function (element) {
    return element.name != 'Bob' && element.country != 'UK';
});
```

How could I use filter (if that is even the best option here) to achive the below output:

```
[
    { name: 'Chris', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'USA' },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS filter through multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071789/js-filter-through-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an OR (||) to filter

```
data.accounts.filter(f => f.name != "Bob" || f.country == 'USA');
```

```js
let data = {
  email: 'email@email.com',
  accounts: [
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Chris', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'USA' },
  ]
}

let filtered = data.accounts.filter(f => f.name != "Bob" || f.country == 'USA');

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Kinglish, I also asked in the answer above but I have tested and using OR does work as intended I am just slightly confused  am I not trying to say x not equal to y AND x2 not equal to y2 rather than OR?

Comment: AND doesn't work because both conditions have to be true in order for anything to get through - NOT being Bob AND NOT being UK. With that, Bob from US will not filter through due to the first condition. In fact, my answer (and the other) are really incomplete because they aren't scalable. You probably want to rephrase your question to have a set of rules (like if there are 2 equal names, prefer US, if its not there, prefer UK, etc).

Comment: I see! That makes sense now, I was going insane trying to understand why it was working that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering out every value that is both *not 'Bob'* and *not 'UK'*.

Here are two possible solutions. The right answer probably depends on exactly what it means to filter "based on 2 factors".

```js
const input = {
  email: 'email@email.com',
  accounts: [
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Chris', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Bob', country: 'USA' },
  ],
};

// Filter out every value with either name 'Bob' or country 'UK'.
const outputV1 = input.accounts.filter(v => v.name !== 'Bob' || v.country !== 'UK');
console.log(outputV1);

// Filter out every value with name 'Bob' and country 'UK'.
const outputV2 = input.accounts.filter(v => `${v.name}-${v.country}` !== 'Bob-UK');
console.log(outputV2);
```

Comment: Your second approach is really interesting! Thanks. I understand the second approach but the first approach of OR doesn't really make sense to me, am I not trying to say x not equal to y AND x2 not equal to y2 rather than or?